# Calculating the $GCD$ of very large numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to compute $gcd(2^{180!},15770708441)$.

I tried to use the Euclidean Algorithm via the implemented Python function, but it takes far too long. My teacher mentioned that we should not compute $2^{180!}$ but rather $2^{180!} \bmod 15770708441$ to keep the numbers small. But if I am not misaking this is exactly what the Euclidean algorithm does.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is two a factor of the latter number? What other primes divide the former number?

Comment: When someone asks you a question involving ridiculously large numbers, it's quite likely there's a trick involved, and you shouldn't jump to the computer right away.

Comment: That said, $2^{180!} \equiv 11620221425 \mod 15770708441$ (computed using repeated squaring).

Comment: Hmm, the real problem wouldn't by any chance be $\gcd(2^{180!}-1, 15770708441)$?  That's less trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No computations or algorithm needed:
The second number is odd, so has *no* (prime) factor $2$ at all.

The first number *only* has prime factor $2$ (repeated $180!$ times).
So they have no common divisor except $1$.